# How to convert a Numbers file to .pdf and still have its formula work

Tags: macos, iwork, numbers

Is there a pdf creator or something that I can convert my Numbers file with all its formula still working. The file is a price calculator with choice of products. 
I dont want the client to change elements so pdf is the way to go (I think).
Please advise.

Comment: PDF's mostly contain static content, so a cell with a working formula is out of the scope of a PDF.
The best way to sent a spreadsheet with working formulas to your client is as a Numbers file, or in case the client does not have iWork, save it as an Excel file.
If you want to lock certain parts of the spreadsheet, that's possible. It's easier in Excel than in Numbers, but how to do that is out of the scope of this question. Ask a new question or rephrase this one about locking spreadsheet contents.

Answer (score 3):

The Numbers to PDF (whether using Print->Save As or Export to… menu commands) will produce PDFs that do not allow running of formula. So unfortunately, no.